# Errores en base de datos de java en sentencias

Tags: java, base-de-datos

Se trata de un programa el cual nos fue provisto por un maestro pero mas sin embargo nuestro maestro no ofrece ayuda y dice que el programa no tiene erroes 
y necesito corregir mi codigo porque el dia de hoy lo entrego

Los errores son los siguientes
(disculpe si son mostrados en imagen pero

```
-**C:\Users\karen\Desktop\based1.java:90: illegal start of expression
        public based1() {**

-C:\Users\karen\Desktop\based1.java:90: ';' expected
        public based1() {


-C:\Users\karen\Desktop\based1.java:141: illegal start of expression
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


-C:\Users\karen\Desktop\based1.java:141: illegal start of expression
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


-C:\Users\karen\Desktop\based1.java:141: ';' expected
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


-C:\Users\karen\Desktop\based1.java:141: ';' expected
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

-C:\Users\karen\Desktop\based1.java:149: ';' expected
             id=Integer.pardeI  nt(linea1);


-C:\Users\karen\Desktop\based1.java:159: ';' expected
f(id>0) {


-C:\Users\karen\Desktop\based1.java:194: 'else' without 'if'
else{


-C:\Users\karen\Desktop\based1.java:207: illegal start of expression
public static void main(String[] args) {


-C:\Users\karen\Desktop\based1.java:207: illegal start of expression
public static void main(String[] args) {


-C:\Users\karen\Desktop\based1.java:207: ';' expected
public static void main(String[] args) {
             ^

-C:\Users\karen\Desktop\based1.java:207: '.class' expected
public static void main(String[] args) {


-C:\Users\karen\Desktop\based1.java:207: ';' expected
public static void main(String[] args) {


-C:\Users\karen\Desktop\based1.java:217: reached end of file while parsing
}


15 errors


Process completed.
```

El codigo del programa es el siguiente

```
// nota:solo ingresa 1 numero registro por vez
import java.awt.*;
import java.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Vector.*;
import java.swing.table.AbstrctModel;
import java.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import java.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class based1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private JTextField textfield1,textfield2,textfield3,textfiedl4,textfield5;
    private JLabel label1,label2,label4,label5;
    private JButton boton1,boton2;
    private JTextArea tecto;

    //variables 
    int id ;
    int aux1=0, aunx2=0,aux3=0,aux4=0,aux5=0;
    float aux6=0;

    String linea="";
    String linea1="";
    String linea2="";
    String linea3="";
    String linea4="";
    String linea5="";

    public void limpiar (){
        textfield1.setText("");
        textfield2.setText("");
        textfield3.setText("");
        textfield4.setText("");
        textfield5.setText("");

    }

    public void tabla1(){
        Vector nombreColumnas=new Vector ();
        nombreColumnas.add("MATRICULA");
        nombreColumnas.add("NOMBRES Y APELLIDOS");
        nombreColumnas.add("EX1");
        nombreColumnas.add("EX2");
        nombreColumnas.add("EX3");
        DefaultTableModel modelo=new DefaultTableModel (nombresColumnas,0);//0
        JTable tabla=new JTable();
        tabla.setModel(modelo);

        try{ Class.forName ("sun.jdbc.odbc.Jdbc0dbcDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1){
            System.out.println(e1.getMessage());}

        try{
            String password ="";
//nombre de la base de datos Acces con extencion *.mdb o *.accdb
            String dbName = "curso1.mdb";
//direccion de la base de datos
            Sting db= System.getProperty ("user.dir") + "\\" + dbName + ";PWD" +password;
            Connection conexion = DriveManger.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:; Driver=Microsoft Access Driver( *.mdb,*.accdb);DBQ=");
            statement estatuto = conexion.createStatement ();
            ResultSet rs = estatuto.executeQuery ("select* FROM lista ORDER BY MATRICULA");
            while (rs.next())

            {
                Vector v= new Vector();
                v.add (rs.getString("MATRICULA"));
                v.add (rs.getString("NOMBRE"));
                v.add (rs.getString("EX1"));
                v.add (rs.getString("EX2"));
                v.add (rs.getString("EX3"));
                modelo.addRow(v);
            }

///WHILE
            JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane (tabla);
            this.getContentPane().add (scroll);
            this.getContentPane().add(scroll);
            scroll.setBounds(350,30,400,300);
            scroll.setVievportView(tabla);
            scroll.setVisible(true);
            estatuto.close();
            conexion.close();
        }catch(SQLException e1) {System.out.println(el.getMessage());


            this.setTitle("Datos Ingresados Correctamente!!!") ;
        }

        public based1() {
            setLayout(null);

            label1=new JLabel("Matricula:");
            label1.setBounds(5,5,100,30);
            add(Label1);
            texfield1=new JTexfield();
            texfield1.setBounds(65,10,100,20);
            add(textfield1);

            label2=new JLabel("Nombres:");
            label1.setBounds(5,25,100,30);
            add(Label2);
            texfield2=new JTexfield();
            texfield2.setBounds(65,32,200,21);
            add(textfield2);

            label3=new JLabel("Nota 1:");
            label3.setBounds(5,53,100,30);
            add(Label3);
            texfield3=new JTexfield();
            texfield3.setBounds(65,55,50,21);
            add(textfield3);

            label4=new JLabel("Nota 2:");
            label4.setBounds(120,53,100,30);
            add(Label4);
            texfield4=new JTexfield();
            texfield4.setBounds(170,55,50,21);
            add(textfield4);

            label5=new JLabel("Nota 3:");
            label5.setBounds(225,53,100,30);
            add(Label5);
            texfield5=new JTexfield();
            texfield5.setBounds(280,55,50,21);
            add(textfield5);

            boton1=new JButton("Grabar");
            boton1.setMnemonic('G');
            boton1.setBounds(10,120,100,30);
            add(boton1);
            boton1.addActionListener(this);

            boton2=new JButton("Salir");
            boton2.setMnemonic('S');
            boton2.setBounds(10,120,100,30);
            add(boton2);
            boton2.addActionListener(this);
        }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource()==boton1) {
            linea="";
            linea1=texfield1.getText();
            linea2=texfield2.getText();
            linea3=texfield3.getText();
            linea4=texfield4.getText();
            linea5=texfield5.getText();
            id=Integer.pardeI  nt(linea1);

            try{
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

            } catch(ClassNotFoundException e1) {

                System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
            }
            f(id>0) {

                try{

                    String password ="";

                    String dbName= "curso1.mdb";


                    String bd= System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\" + dbName + ";PWD=" + password;

                    Connection conexion =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:;Driver=Microsoft Acces Driver (*.mdb,*.accdb);DBQ=");

                    Statement estatuto= conexion.createStatement();

                    aux1=Integer.parseInt(linea1);

                    aux3=Integer.parseInt(linea3);

                    aux4=Integer.parseInt(linea4);

                    aux5=Integer.parseInt(linea5);

                    String q="insert into lista(MATRICULA,NOMBRE,EX1,EX2,EX3)values("+aux1 +", '"+linea2+"',"+aux3+","+aux4+","+aux5+")";

                    estatuto.executeUpdate(q);

                    estatuto.close();

                    conexion.close();
                }catch(SQLException e1){

                    texto.append(e1.getMessage());
                }
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La matricula es incorrecta, debe ser numerica");
            }
            tabla1();
            limpiar();
        }

        if (e.getSource()==boton2) {

            System.exit(0);
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        bassed1 formulario1=new bassed1();

        formulario1.setBounds(1,50,850,450);

        formulario1.setVisible(true);

        formulario1.setTitle("Formulario de ingreso de Datos Java+Acces");
    }

}
```

de antemano pido una disculpa si es de molestia de la comunidad mi pregunta, pero soy nueva en programar y tengo muchas dudas sobre esto, gracias a todos :)

Comment: Primer tip no se recomienda usar `java.util.*` se recomienda usar la clase especifica en su lugar `java.util.Date` por ejemplo

Comment: Segundo punto: si utilizas un IDE ya sea eclipse o netbeas, puedes usar su formateador de codigo para java, ya que asi es muy dificil de leer `Crtl + Shift + F` en eclipse y `Alt + Shift + F` en netbeans

Comment: primero que nada gracias por el consejo, en segunda tambien por corregir el formato, hace tiempo en la version en ingles tenia problemas si metia mucho codigo y la descripcion era pequeña, una disculpa

Comment: Karen que ide usas? Eclipse, Netbeans, IntelliJ idea?

Comment: _pista:_ una declaracion de funcion, tiene que tener un tipo de dato definido, por ejemplo _void_.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta porque no demuestra ningún esfuerzo por parte del autor por siquiera intentar resolver algo

Comment: @KarenLilianaRobledo en Stack Overflow se espera que los usuarios demuestren interés y esfuerzo por solucionarlos problemas, no simplemente esperar que alguien los resuelva por tí. Por favor lee: [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además puedes usar un buen IDE y este te ayudará a solucionar muchos de los errores básicos que tenga tu código.

Comment: en primera pido una disculpa debido a que estuve resolviendo por mi cuenta el codigo (no con mucho exito pero avance algo ) y no me ah dado tiempo de contestar por los trabajos pero todo lo que han dicho es funcional y me ayuddo mucho, no es desinteres, es solo la falta de tiempo, pido una gran disculpa

Comment: Nota, _totalmente_, al margen: Tu profesor es el peor de todos. Que tu profesor no te ayude con los errores habla mucho de por que tu estas preguntado aqui.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no tiene realmente que ver con errores en base de datos con java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ya pude revisar tu código más a detalle. Efectivamente el código fue modificado **intencionalmente** por tu profesor y tiene muchos detalles tipo

```
textfield1 -> notar el cambio de ld
textfiedl1
```

Donde tú tienes que encontrar si alguna expresion está mal escrita.

### No te haremos ningun bien si encontramos los errores por ti

Pero podemos guiarte

### Paso 1

Indenta tu código. Si trabajas con bloc de notas recuerda las reglas básicas. Puedes guiarte de este [muy buen articulo](http://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/tutoriales/indentacion/)

### Paso 2

Haz de nuevo el paso 1. En serio, tu código es totalmente ilegible y debido al número brutal de errores un IDE podría no indentarlo, asi que queda hacerlo a mano

### Paso 3

Sé hábil para encontrar las palabras escritas de forma diferente, por ejemplo `nombreColumnas` y `nombresColumnas`. Hay muchos más regados por doquier.

### Paso 4

Revisa tus `import`s, parece que algunos apuntan a algún lugar incorrecto.

Parece que no hay más, a excepción del consumo de la base de datos que no podemos probar, no tendrías que realizar nada más.

Comment: Sería buena idea le indicaras donde tiene errores en su código para ayudarla.

Comment: @Elenasys No lo considero pertinente, ya que es un ejercicio donde la idea es que practiques tu conocimiento, si alguien mas lo hace por ti no aprenderas nada. Pero claro respeto tu opinion

Comment: me funciono de mucho leer esto, te agradezco bastante la ayuda! disculpa no poder haber contestado en hora, no tuve tiempo con mis demas actividades pero aprecio tu atencion! <3

Comment: @KarenLilianaRobledo por favor considera si esta es la publicación que puedes [aceptar como respuesta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/427/227)

Answer (score 2):

En Java como norma es poner nombres de [clases en Mayúscula](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convenci%C3%B3n_de_Nombres_(Programaci%C3%B3n)#Java).

y revisa esta linea tiene un error:

```
 id=Integer.pardeI  nt(linea1);
```

quedando asi:

```
        linea5=texfield5.getText();
        id=Integer.parseInt(linea1);
```

Este bloque le falta una letra "i"

```
                                   }
f(id>0) {
```

quedando asi:

```
                                 }
if(id>0) {
```

Esos son 2 errores que tiene tu código, podrían ser más, por los cuales obtienes los errores mencionados, te recomiendo como ya lo menciono otro usuario, dependiendo de tu IDE, primeramente [indentes](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentaci%C3%B3n) tu [código](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentaci%C3%B3n#Sangrado_en_C):

Eclipse:
<kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>

Netbeans:
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>

Intellij IDEA
<kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>

---

Temp

```
        //..
        public void tabla1() {
        //..
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                System.out.println(el.getMessage());


                this.setTitle("Datos Ingresados Correctamente!!!");
            }
        //aqui
        public based1() {
        //..
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //..
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
        //..
        }

} //si este fuera class falta en table1 }
```

de ahi este error:

```
'.class' expected
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

Comment: No son 2, son muchos mas

Comment: Lo se por eso lo describo en mi respuesta.

Comment: Esa frase ya queda mejor :)

Comment: @KarenLilianaRobledo ahora mismo no lo puedo mirar pero es posible que usted tenga que llamar a super( "titulo" ); quedando algo asi ->  public based1() { super( "SuTitulo" ); //.. resto de codigo, para uno de sus errores. Saludos

Comment: te agrego una cosa mirar aver que cres igual no me explique bien

Comment: revisar las aperturas y cierres { }, @Elenasys te agrego una cosa mirar aver que cres igual no me explique bien. Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel perfecto, muchas gracias.

Comment: @Elenasys  
Muchisimas gracias, resolvio algunos errores tanto en escritura de algunas sentencias como algunas partes del codigo, desafortunadamente no eh podido darle respuesta a los siguientes: http://postimg.org/image/6kyvpohat/

Comment: Uso  SublimeText 2 con java para  codificar, realice lo comentando arriba con netbeans pero sigo teniendo esos errores mostrados :(

Comment: @KarenLilianaRobledo busca la linea que dice "public based1() {" y agrega la palabra void entre public y based1.

Comment: @KarenLilianaRobledo no se si abra leido los comentarios que deje sobre revisar las { } y tambien puede ver el la repuesta de Elenasys al final, lo curioso es que ya le dije sobre que ese podria ser un problema antes incluso de leer el link que acaba de poner -> illegal start of expression. suele deberse a que estas definiendo un nuevo metodo sin cerrar algun metodo anterior, pero tambien es posible que esta no sea la solucion. Saludos

Comment: @rnrneverdies por que dices que añada void, imagino que usted lo esta confundiendo con un metodo. Saludos

Comment: @KarenLilianaRobledo Por otro lado que public based1() no cumpla con el convenio sobre como nombrar las clases en java NO deja de ser el constructor de la clase, por ello los constructores tienen el mismo nombre que la clase en la que son definidos y nunca tienen tipo de retorno, ni especificado ni void. Asi que aunque su constructor no  use el convenio no deja de ser el constructor, cosa que tambien le comente. Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel correcto, no vi que la clase tenia ese nombre.

Comment: Realice lo que dijo angel, sigo con errores, las llaves no se si sea problema de ellas, re escribi el codigo asignado checandolo minusiosamente y no doy aun del todo con algunos errores, son los mismos

Comment: Disculpen mi codigo ya esta corregido, pero java me esta dando dolores de cabeza con no poderlo ejecutar  con esto  **Note: C:\Users\WIN8\Videos\based1\based1.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.**

Answer (score 0):

Hola me parece Bien las respuestas de los demás, esto es para ayudarte más en lugar de darte el código bien. Te va mi ayuda
Los metodos tienen una estructura como la siguiente:

```
midificadorAcceso valorDeRetorno nombreMetodo(argumentos){ }
```

modificadores de acceso: `default`, `public`, `private`, `protected`
valor de retorno cualquier tipo de dato u Objeto en caso de que el método no regrese algún valor pondrías la palabra reservada void
nombre del metodo el nombre debe de ser alguna acción en caso de que el nombre sea compuesto por dos palabras la primer letra de el nombre por convención es minúscula y la Primera letra de la segúnda en Mayúscula por ejemplo: `setEdad()`
argunentos: el metodo puede recibir o no argumentos si recibe un ejemplo seria el siguiente: `setEdad(int edad)`<----- primero tipo de dato y variable.
en caso de que no reciba argumentos un ejemplo seria el siguiente: `getEdad()`